# Continuous function from a closed disk to real line

Tags: real-analysis

> Is there a continuous function $f:B \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ which is one-one ?, where $B=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$

Suppose it were, then $f(B)=[a,b] \subset \Bbb{R}$. So consider $z \in B$ with $f(z) \neq a,b$. Then $f(B \setminus \{z\})=[a,b] \setminus f(z)$, we have a contradiction. since one is connected the other is not! Is this correct?

Any help?

Comment: Yes, this is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct, assuming you know that $f(B)$ is of the form $[a,b]$ with $a \ne b$.

To show it, note that $B$ is compact and connected so $f(B)$ is also compact and connected in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence $f(B)$ is a segment $[a,b]$. Since $f$ is injective and $B$ is uncountable, $f(B)$ cannot be a singleton so $a \ne b$.